# Spring filters cannot see status codes for requests to static pages

Tags: http, spring-mvc, tomcat, static, servlet-filters

I'm running a Spring Boot Web MVC app which has some pages handled by controllers, and others (static content) configured using a `ResourceHandler`.  I've got my own error handling for the controller methods.  I'm running it under standalone Tomcat.

I want to log every HTTP request and its response, and the HTTP status codes of the responses.  Using Tomcat access logs isn't an option because there is a context for each request (client has an active session) and I want to correlate sessions with pages requested.

I've tried logging using both filters and interceptors.  The problem is that I can't make interceptors see any requests to static resources - I think they only work for pages that are handled by controllers - and the filters will log requests to static resources but they always log the response as 200, even when it's a 404.  I haven't got my own default error page set up (and I'm not that interested in setting one, I just need to set the status) so when I request a static resource that doesn't exist I'll see something like this in my logs:

```
2015-03-26 16:02:46.770  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.app.config.RequestLoggingFilter   : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=request; Method=GET; resource=/resources/missing.html
2015-03-26 16:02:46.770  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.app.config.RequestLoggingFilter   : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=response; Status=200; Length=unknown; resource=/resources/missing.html
2015-03-26 16:02:46.788  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.app.config.RequestLoggingFilter   : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=request; Method=GET; resource=/error
2015-03-26 16:02:46.788  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.app.config.RequestLoggingFilter   : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=response; Status=404; Length=unknown; resource=/error
2015-03-26 16:02:46.811  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.a.c.RequestLoggingInterceptor      : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=request; Method=GET; resource=/error
2015-03-26 16:02:46.839  INFO 26576 --- [http-bio-8080-exec-3] a.c.u.a.c.RequestLoggingInterceptor      : CONTEXT=unknown; Type=response; Status=404; Length=unknown; resource=/error
```

As you can see, only the filter picks up any request/response for a static resource, but both filter and interceptor later pick up the request and response for my missing `/error` page.

Note that I have [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088066/spring-boot-in-standalone-tomcat-ignores-exceptions-set-in-deferredresults), but as far as I know it's only affecting DeferredResults - it shouldn't be affecting the appearance of the status in the filter chain for a static page request.

How can I log the real response status for requests to missing static resources?  I don't really mind how this is accomplished - through filters or using interceptors or by overriding the controller for `/error`.

Here's my AppConfiguration which adds the static resource handlers and the interceptors:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableConfigurationProperties
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class AppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private MyAppProperties properties;

        @Autowired
        SessionDataArgumentResolver sessionDataArgumentResolver;

        // Serve up static files directly from the external directory
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {


            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                    properties.getExternalDirectoryURI("resources/").toString()).setCachePeriod(
                    properties.getCacheControlMaxAge());

            // At least after the controller registry
            registry.setOrder(10);
        }

        @Override
        public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
            argumentResolvers.add(sessionDataArgumentResolver);
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new RequestLoggingInterceptor());
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up posting an issue on Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2817
The answer was embarrassingly simple: I needed to log the response status *after* invoking filterChain.doFilter:

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
LOGGER.info("HTTP request for resource {} - status {}", request.getRequestURI(), response.getStatus());
}
```

It works perfectly after doing that.